# data aggregation based on timestamp lookback

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, sqldf

I am looking for a data aggregation approach based on timestamps.
Here is my sample data:

```
new <- data.table( date = as.POSIXct( c( "2016-03-06 12:23:00", "2016-03-07 12:21:00", "2016-03-08 12:26:00" ,"2016-03-09 12:30:00","2016-03-10 12:50:00",
                                         "2016-03-06 12:20:00","2016-03-07 12:20:00","2016-03-08 12:20:00","2016-03-09 12:20:00","2016-03-10 12:20:00")   
), data.count = c( 1,7,10,15,12,11,23,35,21,11 ) )
```

What i am trying to achieve is count of `data.count` grouped by each date and its preceding two dates(or preceding `n` dates since sample is small so i have chosen to go with preceding two dates )   :

```
 date     previous_date  count
2016-03-09 2016-03-07       30
2016-03-09 2016-03-08       45
2016-03-09 2016-03-09       36
2016-03-10 2016-03-08       45
2016-03-10 2016-03-09       36
2016-03-10 2016-03-10       33
```

So the sample output looks like for `2016-03-10` we have three rows , one the count on `2016-03-10` and other two are its preceding dates`2016-03-09, 2016-03-08`.

**Attempt One:**

Here is my first approach :

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(as.Date(new$date))))
{
  assign(paste0(unique(as.Date(new$date))[i]), new%>%
  group_by(unique(as.Date(new$date))[i],as.Date(new$date)) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(count= sum(data.count))%>% 
     filter(.[[1]] > .[[2]]))

}
```

This give me for each unique dates , its group_by with all other unique dates in the data set.
However i am yet to figure out how to  limit my result to just `last 2` or `last n` dates.

**Attempt Two**

Here is my second try where i am able to finally figure out the result the way i want it to be:

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(as.Date(new$date))))
{

    assign(paste0(unique(as.Date(new$date))[i]), new%>%
             group_by(unique(as.Date(new$date))[i],as.Date(new$date)) %>%
             dplyr::summarise(count= sum(data.count))%>% 
             filter(.[[1]] >= .[[2]])%>%
             arrange(desc(.[[2]]))%>%
             top_n(3))

}
```

However there seems to be a catch with `2016-03-10` date :

```
2016-03-10          2016-03-09    36
2016-03-10          2016-03-08    45
2016-03-10          2016-03-07    30
```

It doesn't return :

```
2016-03-10          2016-03-10    23
2016-03-10          2016-03-09    36
2016-03-10          2016-03-08    45
```

There seems to be sum issue with `top_n()` as

```
 new%>%
     group_by(unique(as.Date(new$date))[5],as.Date(new$date)) %>%
     dplyr::summarise(count= sum(data.count))%>% 
     filter(.[[1]] >= .[[2]])%>%
     arrange(desc(.[[2]]))
```

This returns me this :

```
2016-03-10          2016-03-10    23
2016-03-10          2016-03-09    36
2016-03-10          2016-03-08    45
2016-03-10          2016-03-07    30
2016-03-10          2016-03-06    12
```

Which is perfectly fine, just that top_n() of this not returning

```
2016-03-10          2016-03-10    23
```

which ideally it should, as this is working perfectly fine with other dates.
Let me know if you would be able to figure whats going wrong in here.

Comment: how about gaps in your data (missing dates), do you ignore them or do you want the count for the last n existing dates?

Comment: Can we assume that every data occurs only once (or zero times - see my prev. comment)? You are asking for "grouping by each date", but in your sample data each date occurs only once so there is no need to group the data.

Comment: Yes, i would ignore missing dates, just that i want to look into the dates in my data set, so for each date  get the previous two dates and the date itself and report the count. Apologies, i have updated my data set now, so now we have repeated entries for a date.

Comment: It would also work if we can just look at last 2 days for each date and if there is a gap (let say the second nearest date doesn't exist ), we can just report `NA` or any flag as such

Comment: Should the count on the first line (date: 2016-03-09, previous_date: 2016-03-07) be 111, 7 + 10 + 15 + 23 + 35 + 21, or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually not as , my output would be like : `each date, preceding two dates, sum(data.count of the preceding dates)`. Apologies if i was not clear in the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I am very confused now about the expected results after changing the question (and the expected result you mention as example is not what I get but perhaps you have updated the data in `new` only without adjusting the results...).

Nevertheless, *I guess* this is what you want (**you can configure the number of previous days at step #2**):

```
require(data.table)

# 1. Aggregate counts per date (ignoring the time)
new[, date.only := as.Date(date)]  # get rid of time
new.agg <- new[, .(count = .N, sum = sum(data.count) ), by = date.only]

# 2. Calculate lower date boundary
number.of.prev.days <- 2  # configure your date range (bucket size) here
new.agg[, previous_date := as.Date(date.only - number.of.prev.days)]

# 3. Create one row per date that contributes to a date bucket
new.agg.items <- new.agg[new.agg, .(date.only = x.date.only, sum), on = .(date.only <= date.only, date.only >= previous_date), by = .EACHI]

# col names cosmetics required due to counter-intuitive non-equi join column names...
# See: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1700
setnames(new.agg.items, 1, "bucket.from.date")
setnames(new.agg.items, 2, "bucket.to.date")

# 4. order descending (required for a cumsum going back in time!)
new.agg.items <- new.agg.items[order(bucket.from.date, -date.only)]

# 5. Cumsum over the groups (date buckets) finally
result <- new.agg.items[, .(from.date = date.only, sum = cumsum(sum)), by = .(bucket.from.date, bucket.to.date)]
```

which results in

```
> new.agg
    date.only count sum previous_date
1: 2016-03-06     2  12    2016-03-04
2: 2016-03-07     2  30    2016-03-05
3: 2016-03-08     2  45    2016-03-06
4: 2016-03-09     2  36    2016-03-07
5: 2016-03-10     2  23    2016-03-08

> new.agg.items
    bucket.from.date bucket.to.date  date.only sum
 1:       2016-03-06     2016-03-04 2016-03-06  12
 2:       2016-03-07     2016-03-05 2016-03-07  30
 3:       2016-03-07     2016-03-05 2016-03-06  12
 4:       2016-03-08     2016-03-06 2016-03-08  45
 5:       2016-03-08     2016-03-06 2016-03-07  30
 6:       2016-03-08     2016-03-06 2016-03-06  12
 7:       2016-03-09     2016-03-07 2016-03-09  36
 8:       2016-03-09     2016-03-07 2016-03-08  45
 9:       2016-03-09     2016-03-07 2016-03-07  30
10:       2016-03-10     2016-03-08 2016-03-10  23
11:       2016-03-10     2016-03-08 2016-03-09  36
12:       2016-03-10     2016-03-08 2016-03-08  45

> result
    bucket.from.date bucket.to.date  from.date sum
 1:       2016-03-06     2016-03-04 2016-03-06  12
 2:       2016-03-07     2016-03-05 2016-03-07  30
 3:       2016-03-07     2016-03-05 2016-03-06  42
 4:       2016-03-08     2016-03-06 2016-03-08  45
 5:       2016-03-08     2016-03-06 2016-03-07  75
 6:       2016-03-08     2016-03-06 2016-03-06  87
 7:       2016-03-09     2016-03-07 2016-03-09  36
 8:       2016-03-09     2016-03-07 2016-03-08  81
 9:       2016-03-09     2016-03-07 2016-03-07 111
10:       2016-03-10     2016-03-08 2016-03-10  23
11:       2016-03-10     2016-03-08 2016-03-09  59
12:       2016-03-10     2016-03-08 2016-03-08 104
```

If you prefer the result using the same columns and names as the OP requested:

```
# Optionally: Rename and choose columns as the OP asked for
result[, .(date = bucket.from.date, previous_date = from.date, count = sum)]
```

to get

```
         date previous_date count
 1: 2016-03-06    2016-03-06    12
 2: 2016-03-07    2016-03-07    30
 3: 2016-03-07    2016-03-06    42
 4: 2016-03-08    2016-03-08    45
 5: 2016-03-08    2016-03-07    75
 6: 2016-03-08    2016-03-06    87
 7: 2016-03-09    2016-03-09    36
 8: 2016-03-09    2016-03-08    81
 9: 2016-03-09    2016-03-07   111
10: 2016-03-10    2016-03-10    23
11: 2016-03-10    2016-03-09    59
12: 2016-03-10    2016-03-08   104
```